# Is it possible to append subroutines to a Raku module at runtime?

Tags: metaprogramming, raku

I would like to be able to add a `sub` to a module `Foo` at runtime.

In Perl, I would do something like:

```perl
*{'My::Module::foo'} = \sub { 'FOO!' };
```

I know Raku doesn't have TypeGlobbing like Perl. Ideally it would be something like:

```
use MONKEY;

module Foo {};

Foo.^add-sub('foo', sub { 'FOO!' });
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
module Foo {}
Foo::<&added-sub> = sub { 99 }
say Foo::added-sub; # 99
```

See also:

- [My answer to **Can't interpolate variable in another namespace**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65513383/cant-interpolate-variable-in-another-namespace-raku/65516514#65516514:%7E:text=Statically%20specified%20packages%2C%20dynamically%20specified%20variable).
- [My nanswer to **Symbols Created in Stash at Runtime Not Available in PseudoStash**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68886261/1077672).

Comment: nanswer? (spelling...).

Comment: @jubiliatious1 A *magic* spello.  I write "nanswer" to refer to any SO answer I write that is an answer in at least some senses (in particular, that I've posted it using SO's answer feature) but arguably *not* an answer in some other senses. (The word "nanswer" is a play on the IEEE float value representing what normally *is* a number when in fact it's *not* a number, aka `NaN`.) If someone assumes it's a spello, that's OK. If you click the link you'll see it's an example of what I do if I decide to refer to an answer as a nanswer; I explain why I think it is arguably not an answer.

Comment: But you wrote "nanwser" ( not "nanswer"). Presuming you want last four letters "SWER" ??